# How can I print out a hash map's values as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

```
for (var i = 0, keys = Object.keys(map), ii = keys.length; i < ii; i++) {
  console.log(keys[i] + '|' + map[keys[i]]);
}
```

I have a map that I would like to print out in the following format:

```
customer1|asdfasdf,asdfasdf,asdfa
customer2|adf
customer3|asdf,rthrg
customer5|dfgbdf
customer4|bfdgbfg,bdfgb,dfgb
customer6|sdfgf
customer7|xcvb,xvcbff
```

Instead I get this. Each of those objects contains the list of strings that I would like to print above. How can I do this?

```
customer1|[object Object]
customer2|[object Object]
customer3|[object Object]
customer5|[object Object]
customer4|[object Object]
customer6|[object Object]
customer7|[object Object]
```

Comment: Can you provide the map that is used, or an example map with the same structure? Without it, it is very hard to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found the answer. I need to print the list.

```
for (var i = 0, keys = Object.keys(map), ii = keys.length; i < ii; i++) {
  console.log(keys[i] + '|' + map[keys[i]].list);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the normal `forEach` loop and use it this way:

```js
var cust = {
  customer1: ["cus1Value1", "cus1Value2", "cus1Value3"],
  customer2: ["cus2Value1", "cus2Value2", "cus2Value3", "cus3value4"],
  customer3: ["cus3Value1", "cus3Value2"],
  customer4: ["cus4Value1", "cus4Value2"],
  customer5: ["cus5Value1", "cus5Value2"]
};

var keys = Object.keys(cust);
keys.forEach(key=>{
  console.log(key + '|' + cust[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can so something like this:

```js
function printKeys(map){
 for (var i = 0, keys = Object.keys(map), ii = keys.length; i < ii; i++) {
  val = map[keys[i]];
  if(typeof val === 'object'){
   printKeys(val);
  }else{
   console.log(keys[i] + '|' + map[keys[i]]);
  }
 }
}

map = {a :1, b:2, c:3, d: {d1: 4}};
printKeys(map);
```

Hope it helps!